# Add synonym or merge [.rdlc] with [rdlc] on StackOverflow

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I noticed that there's a tag for both rdlc and .rdlc:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rdlc/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.rdlc/info

These seem like they should be synonyms or be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, with the help of Gustav, all questions with [.rdlc](/questions/tagged/.rdlc) are now retagged to [rdlc](/questions/tagged/rdlc) and updated the tag wiki for .rdlc